# Проблема с классом Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть класс Profile с полями, при изменении объектов которого отслеживается ошибка. Как сделать, чтобы при обновлении приложения обновлялся и класс.

```
private fun subscribeOnErrors() {
    if(!baseViewModel().activateProOutcome.hasObservers()) {
        baseViewModel().errorOutcome.observe(this, Observer {
            when (it) {
                is Outcome.Failure -> {
                    if (activity is BaseActivity) {
                        (activity as BaseActivity).processApiError(it)
                    }
                }
                is Outcome.Success -> {
                    if (activity is BaseActivity) {
                        (activity as BaseActivity).processCodeError(it.data)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

fun processApiError(it: Outcome.Failure<*>) {
    if (it.error == null) {
        showToast(R.string.global_error)
    } else {
        if (it.error.MessageType == 1) {
            showDialogError(it.error.MessageText, false, object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(p0: DialogInterface?, p1: Int) {
                    finish()
                }
            })
        } else {
            showDialogError(it.error.MessageText)
        }
    }
}
```

Это Profile

```
data class Profile(
    var Coins:String,
    var Pro:Int,
    var Repost: Int,
    var RehearsalTime: Int,
    var Tasks:ArrayList<ProfileTasks>,
    var BallsArray:ArrayList<String>,
    var Rehearsal:ArrayList<Rehearsal>,
    var RehearsalPrice:Int,

    @PrimaryKey
    var ID: 1
)
```

Это Error

```
data class ErrorModel (
    var MessageText:String,
    var MessageType:Int
)
```

Comment: Из данного вопроса, непонятно как вам помочь, переформулируйте его и добавьте контекста\кода

Comment: при обновлении приложения вы обновляете классы приложения, обновите и свой класс Profile, как считаете нужным или в чем именно проблема обновления из вопроса совершенно не понятно

Comment: @pavlofff, проблема в том, что он как раз таки думает, что у меня лишний объект, если я добавляю что то новое.

Comment: Вопрос про `Room` или `Rx`?

Comment: Вопрос про Rx))